# How can I tell what updates will be made via yum update?

Tags: yum

I'm trying to figure out how to see all the updates that will be applied by `yum update`, before running it.  Is there a simple command for that?

My understanding is that `yum list updates` only list what has been updated previously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sudo yum update --assumeno

this will list all available updates without actually updating anything, assuming you have a yum version that support the switch. otherwise just be careful because by default it will ask you before it does the update and you can still say no.

Comment: You can also use `yum shell`, which will even let you tweak what will be done before it's done. From the shell, `update` will create an update transaction. Then you can use transaction commands like `ts list` to view it, `ts solve` to include any dependencies, and finally `ts run` to execute it.